# Excel processes blocks log off or shutdown workstation

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, shutdown, microsoft-office-2016

We do see lately (appr. 2 months now) that users complain about not beïng able to log off or shutdown the workstation. This occurs on laptops as wel on workstations. We have narrowed the issue down to orphaned Excel processes which then should be killed by hand or by answering the close question (one for each process).

[Remote Process List shwoing one visible Excel (highlighted) and 3 orpaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waGn9.jpg)

Users sometimes see one or two Excel's open which they can save & close, but some keep orphaned and not visible to the user. Remotely closing the processes using 'pskill \workstation Excel' instantly solves the issue?

Environment:

- Windows 10 x64 1909 (with latest patches)
- Office 365 x86 deferred channel (same issue with x64 build)

Comment: Office has a couple self repair options, it's probably worth eliminating those are solutions first.

Comment: We've did Office 365 repairs. We asked to close all (visible) Excel processes. Nothing helped. We do test now with DisableMergeInstance=1 (REG_DWORD) in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options. I'll post the result asap.

Comment: Registry entry didn't help, orpaned Excel files still are created and still block logoff or shutdown. 

In the link mentioned in the main text someone suggests it has to do with Ivanti Workspace. We also do run Ivanti Workspace but these issues also exists on non-Ivanti Workspace workstations. We had a talk with Ivanti support engineers stating it could have somthing to do with capturing user settings for applications but tests with this were negative.